# How to add a byte array resource from DB to a KieFileSystem and build a KieBuilder?

Tags: drools

I am using drools 6.2. I am getting a Run time exception when I try to write it as

```
kFile = kService.newKieFileSystem();        
resource = kService.getResources().newByteArrayResource(drlFileData)
    .setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL);         
kFile.write(resource);
```

Comment: Why don't you offer full exception message? It would be great if you can [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult for the KieFileSystem to determine a path name from a mere byte array. Therefore, provide a path name:

```
kfs.write( "src/main/resources/whatever.drl", resource );
```

Comment: Will this create a file in the path mentioned?